# Requesting a word for this sentence

Tags: word-request

I want to write a sentence:

> I have the right to voice my __

The word I'm looking for to fill the gap means unsatisfaction and resentment/complain but in a more subtle and formal way.

I vaguely remember a word starting with the alphabets: disc--, which perhaps would suffice here, but can't seem to remember or find. However, I'm not limited to that word only; any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: The word you're trying to remember – it wouldn't happen to be _disgust_, would it? _I have the right to voice my disgust._

Comment: @J.R. If it is, it certainly isn't "subtle and formal". :)

Comment: @J.R.  Not really. Every time I think about this word, all that comes to my mind is the word "discernment", which, I know, means something else entirely. But I think ( I may be extremely wrong, in which case I'm sorry to have wasted your time) that there a word that is may be spelt similar to this, with the meaning of dissatisfaction. I have spent 2 hrs looking for the word; vocabulary is not my strong point.

Comment: @Sara do you mean _discontent_?

Comment: dissatisfaction?

Comment: You might consider using 'dismay'.

Comment: disgruntlement?

Comment: disagreement, disquietude, a right to voice my misgivings, my reservations ....?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the beginning you think the word might have, it sounds like you're looking for "[dissent](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/dissent_1)".

> refusal to agree with an official decision or accepted opinion
>    - *These   voices of dissent   grew louder.*

If you prefer to be even more subtle, you can use "[opinion](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/opinion)".

> your ideas or beliefs about a particular subject
>    - *The two women had very different opinions about drugs.*

Your opinion, can be for or against the topic but using it in your example sentence would generally imply that you're against the topic and want to explain why.

Comment: You could combine these: _I have the right to voice my dissenting opinion._

Comment: @J.R. Very true. :)

Answer (score 4):

One possibility would be:

> I have the right to voice my **disapproval**.

[***disapproval***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/disapproval):

> 1) failure or refusal to approve; rejection
>   2) unfavorable opinion; condemnation

Comment: In a similar vein, "dissatisfaction" works nicely here.

Answer (score 4):

You could also say:

> I have the right to voice my **[grievances](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/grievance)**.

**Example sentence:**

> I have the right to voice my *grievances*, along with every other
>   citizen.

Answer (score 1):

The perfect word here is 'displeasure'. This clearly states your feelings, whilst inviting the recipient to put things right if they value your friendship or custom (depending on the context). If you use the word 'disgust', they might feel you are so angry it is not worth reasoning with you for the moment, or trying to find a solution. Using the word 'grievance' would suggest that things have gone beyond the stage where friendly discussion might rectify things and that any ongoing correspondence will perhaps involve authorities, lawyers et al.